# vb.net webclient class throw an out of memory exception

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I use VB.Net with VisualStudio 2015 and .net 4.5.2.

I use the System.Net.WebClient class to UPLOAD ASYNC FILES into a webserver with the methode UploadFileAsync(address as URI, fileName as string) but a System.OutOfMemoryException accured when the fileSize is too large...

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you handle that file? opening, reading or something else which can load whole file in the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

There was an error here :

```
postStreamHeaders = boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""var1""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "val1" & vbCrLf
postStreamHeaders = boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""var2""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "val2" & vbCrLf
postStreamFooters = boundary & "--"
```

The good syntax is :

```
postStreamHeaders = "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""var1""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "val1" & vbCrLf
postStreamHeaders &= "--" & boundary & vbCrLf & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""var2""" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "val2" & vbCrLf
postStreamFooters = "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf
```

Hope this may help someone else ...